# I would like to iterate the dynamic table through xpath but couldn't do it in katalon studio....Anyone expertise in Katalon Studio?

Tags: web, dynamic, datatables, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

```
String beforeXpath= "//div[@data-dyn-rowid='"
String afterXpath="']//input[@name='ONGSROActivityLine_Quantity']"

WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

List list = driver.findElements(By.xpath('//input[@name=\'ONGSROActivityLine_Quantity\']'))

int countList = list.size()

println(countList)

for (def i = 1; i <=countList; i++) {

    List<String> actualXpath = beforeXpath+ i +afterXpath

    String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a")
    driver.findElements(By.xpath(actualXpath)).sendKeys(selectAll)
    driver.findElements(By.xpath(actualXpath)).sendKeys(Keys.DELETE)
    driver.findElements(By.xpath(actualXpath)).sendKeys(Keys.DELETE)
    driver.findElements(By.xpath(actualXpath)).sendKeys("10")


     //WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject("//div[@data-dyn-rowid='"+i+"']//input[@name='ONGSROActivityLine_Quantity']"),Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, 'a'))

  // WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject("//div[@data-dyn-rowid='"+i+"']//input[@name='ONGSROActivityLine_Quantity']"), 
        //Keys.chord(Keys.DELETE))

   // WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject('Native Trax/Page_ONGNativeTraxCount -- Finance and Operations/input_Qty_ONGSROActivityLine_Quantity'), 
       // '10')

   // WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject('Native Trax/Page_ONGNativeTraxCount -- Finance and Operations/input_Qty_ONGSROActivityLine_Quantity'), 
     //   Keys.chord(Keys.ENTER))
}
```

**Error**

> Reason:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '//div[@data-dyn-rowid='1']//input[@name='ONGSROActivityLine_Quantity']' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'
>       at Native Trax.run(Native Trax:84)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:169)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:142)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:91)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:157)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
>       at TempTestSuite1573849158556.run(TempTestSuite1573849158556.groovy:36)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast an object of string class to the list class.

Just try a normal string for the actualXpath:

```
def actualXpath = beforeXpath+ i +afterXpath
```

instead of

```
List<String> actualXpath = beforeXpath+ i +afterXpath
```

Comment: DEBUG testcase.Native Trax                     - 1: actualXpath = beforeXpath + i + afterXpath
 DEBUG testcase.Native Trax                     - 2: xpath(actualXpath)).sendKeys(Keys.chord(CONTROL, "a"))
 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ Test Cases/Native Trax FAILED.
Reason:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.sendKeys() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [a]

Comment: You are sending `Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a")` as a string to `sendKeys()` method. Comment that line out and write the next line as `driver.findElements(By.xpath(actualXpath)).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"))`.

Comment: edited the code as guided but still throwing an error.

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.sendKeys() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [a]
 at Native Trax.run(Native Trax:77)

Comment: This is a known issue in Katalon: https://forum.katalon.com/t/webui-sendkeys-should-accept-an-org-openqa-selenium-keys-argument. But I still think it should work. Can you recheck if the `List<String> actualXpath... ` is commented out?